# only copying files with unique content

Tags: bash, unique, copying

I am trying to filter trough data, and would like to copy only the files which have only 1 representative of a certain group. For example, the file might look like:

> sample_AAAAA_9824_r1
>   GGAAGCATCGTGGGAACTGCTTCACTAAGAAGGAAGTCACAGTTACTTCATAGATATCCATCACTAAAYGTGAGTAGATTGTGTTAATGTGTTATATATGACTGAAAAATTTTGCCTGGATCAGAATACGAAACCTTCTTGAGATATTGTAATGAATTTCAGTCATATGAGAAGTGATGGAGGGGGTGTGAATACATATACTGTGTCATTATCCATGCAGTATkATACTRCAAAGTTC-----
>   sample_AACCC_12358_r1
>   GGAAGCATCGTGGGAACTGCTTCACTAAGAAGGAAGTCACAGTTACTTCATAGATATCCATCACTAAATGTGAGTAGATTGTGTTAATGTGTTATATATGACTGAAAAWTTTTGCCTGGATCAGAATACGAAACCTTCTTGAGATATTGTAATGAATTTCAGTCATATGAGAAGTGATGGAGGGGGTGTGAATACATATACTGTGTCATTATCCATGCAGTATTATACTGCAAAGTTC-----
>   sample_AATTT_3905_r1
>   GGAAGCATCGTGGGAACTGCTTCACTAAGAAGGAAGTCACAGTTACTTCATAGATATCCATCACTAAATGTGAGTAGATTGTGTTAATGTGTTATATATGACTGAAAAATTTTGCCTGGATCAGAATACGAAACCTTCTTGAGATATTTTCAGTCATATGAGAATTGATGGAGGGGGTGTGAATACATATACTGTGTCATTATCCATGCAGTATGATACTACAAAGTTCCTTCCCATA-----
>   sample_ACGTA_178_r1
>   GGAAGCATCGTAGGAACTGCTTCACTAAGAAGGAAGTCACAGTTACTTCATAGATATCCATCACTAAATGTGAGTAGATTGTGTTAATGTGTTATATATGACTGAAAATTTTTGCCTGGATCAGAATACGAAACCTTCTTGAGATATTGTAATGAATTTCAGTCATATGAGAAGCGATGGAGGGGGTGTGAATACATATACTGTGTCATTATCCATGCAGTATGATACTACAAAGTTC-----
>   sample_ACTGC_9933_r1
>   GGAAGCATCGTRGGAACTGCTTCACTAAGAAGGAAGTCACAGTTACTTCATAGATATCCATCACTAAATGTGAGTAGATTGTGTTAATGTGTTATATATGACTGAAAAwTTTTGCCTGGATCAGAATACGAAACCTTCTTGAGATATTGTAATGAATTTCAGTCATATGAGAAGYGATGGAGGGGGTGTGAATACATATACTGTGTCATTATCCATGCAGTATGATACTACAAAGTTC-----

I have about 36000 of these files, and would like to copy only those to a different folder which have only one entry per sample (1 sample is for example sample ACTGC). There are 26 sample "numbers", consisting of 5 letters (e.g. AAAAA, AATTTT, ACGTC,...) the following number and "r1" is irrelevant.

I have been looking through different bash scripts for this, but cannot find the exact thing i need. I can count the occurence of each sample in a file, but this is probably not the way to go...

any help is greatly appreciated,
Yannick

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you already tried and what is not working.

Comment: You should really be using a database to store this information, not thousands of individual files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to compare using `cmp` based on the output of `sort` vs the output of `sort | uniq`:

```
for f in files/*
do if cmp -s <(grep sample ${f} | cut -d'_' -f2 | sort) <(grep sample ${f} | cut -d'_' -f2 | sort | uniq)
then
    echo "copying file ${f} here..."
    # ... copy
else
    "not copying file ${f} here" # do nothing...!
fi
done
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply, I think this will work!